# Jenkins and artifactory, rtdownload windows agents, "Could not create nor write to file" C:\Windows\Temp\1234567890123\

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

We can not download from Artifactory onto Windows agents,

It looks to us like it’s a permission problem on the temporary download folder on Windows agents, i.e. C:\Windows\Temp\14315663966815098879...
A folder is made in C:\Windows\Temp but it's not read or writeable.

It had been working, we think it may have stopped when we recently updated Jenkins.

The agent runs as a service under sysytem.

We have versions

```
Jenkins: 2.414.2
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin: 3.18.11

win10 agent.
Agent version 3131.vf2b_b_798b_ce99
```

A log here

```
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 3.18.11
Searching for artifacts...
Found 1 artifacts.
Beginning to resolve Build Info published dependencies.
Downloading 'stz-software-release-local/Security Manager Services/0.2.0.350-65/deployment.zip'...
[Thread downloader_1] downloading C:\Windows\TEMP\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services/0.2.0.350-65/deployment.zip1 as part of file stz-software-release-local/Security Manager Services/0.2.0.350-65/deployment.zip threw an exception: java.io.IOException: Could not create nor write to file: C:\Windows\Temp\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services\0.2.0.350-65\deployment.zip1
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.saveInputStreamToFile(DownloadToFile.java:34)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.setResponse(DownloadToFile.java:40)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.processResponse(JFrogService.java:143)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.execute(JFrogService.java:123)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.downloadToFile(ArtifactoryManager.java:128)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.lambda$doConcurrentDownload$0(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\TEMP\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services\0.2.0.350-65\deployment.zip1 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.saveInputStreamToFile(DownloadToFile.java:30)
    ... 6 more
[Thread downloader_0] downloading C:\Windows\TEMP\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services/0.2.0.350-65/deployment.zip0 as part of file stz-software-release-local/Security Manager Services/0.2.0.350-65/deployment.zip threw an exception: java.io.IOException: Could not create nor write to file: C:\Windows\Temp\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services\0.2.0.350-65\deployment.zip0
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.saveInputStreamToFile(DownloadToFile.java:34)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.setResponse(DownloadToFile.java:40)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.processResponse(JFrogService.java:143)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.execute(JFrogService.java:123)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.downloadToFile(ArtifactoryManager.java:128)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.lambda$doConcurrentDownload$0(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\TEMP\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services\0.2.0.350-65\deployment.zip0 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.saveInputStreamToFile(DownloadToFile.java:30)
    ... 6 more
[Thread downloader_2] downloading C:\Windows\TEMP\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services/0.2.0.350-65/deployment.zip2 as part of file stz-software-release-local/Security Manager Services/0.2.0.350-65/deployment.zip threw an exception: java.io.IOException: Could not create nor write to file: C:\Windows\Temp\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services\0.2.0.350-65\deployment.zip2
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.saveInputStreamToFile(DownloadToFile.java:34)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.setResponse(DownloadToFile.java:40)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.processResponse(JFrogService.java:143)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.execute(JFrogService.java:123)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.downloadToFile(ArtifactoryManager.java:128)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.lambda$doConcurrentDownload$0(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\TEMP\14315663966815098879\Security Manager Services\0.2.0.350-65\deployment.zip2 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.DownloadToFile.saveInputStreamToFile(DownloadToFile.java:30)
    ... 6 more
FATAL: java.io.IOException: Unknown I/O error listing contents of directory: C:\Windows\TEMP\14315663966815098879
java.io.IOException: Unknown I/O error listing contents of directory: C:\Windows\TEMP\14315663966815098879
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:2190)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:333)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1192)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.downloadFileConcurrently(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:256)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.downloadArtifact(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:209)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from UKSTZ-S-NUC002.ad.iar.com/192.168.1.72:60174
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1192)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1181)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.setUp(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:387)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:158)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.downloadArtifact(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:222)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.downloadArtifact(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:184)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.downloadDependencies(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:123)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.DependenciesDownloaderHelper.downloadDependencies(DependenciesDownloaderHelper.java:83)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecsHelper.downloadArtifactsBySpec(SpecsHelper.java:142)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.FilesResolverCallable.invoke(FilesResolverCallable.java:51)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.FilesResolverCallable.invoke(FilesResolverCallable.java:21)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3578)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

To isolate the problem, we made a very simple freestyle project. All it does is download a file from the Artifactory and in Powershells echo “hello world”.

The file should have been downloaded and in the workspace.

we also tried relocating the agent's temporary folder to an alternate directory that possesses complete accessibility. However, this did not yield any change.

The anomaly appears to be related to the permissions associated with the folder generated by the 'rtdownload' function It appears to have very restricted permissions, limited to only the 'machinename$' principal with full control.

The agent runs as a service under system.

Any sugestions apericated.

Comment: Although we can not explain why this suddenly stopped working. We found that running the service under a local user account (not localsystem) fixed the issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

I would do 2 things.
First, You have spaces in the path (Security Manager Services) I would change this to Security_MAnager_Services as spaces tend to create issues when trying to find paths.

If the first recommendation is not working, I would raise this issue in the open-source project https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/issues

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. We have narrowed it down further. If we start the service as localsystem we get the error. If we start the service as a different account, then it all works. We'll take a look over at GitHub for the plug-in. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your jenkins might be running as Local System Account - Update to a account that has admin privileges.